# Циклы. Поочерёдное вычитание первого элемента массива из первого и каждого последующего массива

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

Приветствую всех кто читает!
Поставил перед собой задачу по циклам на плюсах. Условие таково: имеется массив из n чисел (Переменная n задаётся с клавиатуры, но я ищу возможность автоматического присвоения значения переменной на основание введённого цикла (этот вопрос не основной, но если у кого-то появятся идеи - буду рад Вашей помощи)), сам массив также записывается с клавиатуры. Для него выполняется цикл по вычитанию первого числа самого же массива. Следующим действием нужно повторить операцию для уже сгенерированного массива (arr[n]-= temp, где temp = arr[0]).
Суть вопроса следующая: какие есть способы реализации, учитывая что переменную temp нужно перезаписать после каждой итерации, а конечным результатом цикла должно быть единственное значение (конечный вывод в консоль каждого нового массива в новую строку с конечным пирамидальным видом, где последнее число будет разницей этого же числа с первыми элементами всех циклов)
Если Вы считаете что вопрос глупый, то заранее прошу прощения. Поиски в гугле не дал ответов на поставленный вопрос, поэтому прошу подсказку у Знатоков.
Благодарю за каждый ответ

UPD:

```
    int n;
    int* arr = new int[n];
    int temp;

    cout << "Введите колличество элементов в массиве ";
    cin >> n;
    
    cout << " Запишите массив: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    temp = arr[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] -= temp;
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
```

Скорректирую вопрос, так как первичный вариант задан некорректно. Тот способ который мне известен предполагает окончание цикла по достижению числа ноль, но это сразу же приведёт к завершению работы кода, так как ноль ожидается в каждой итерации цикла. Необходимо найти решение, при котором цикл будет выполнятся полностью и завершаться выводом всех массивов, где последний массив является числом - разницей последнего числа первично заданного массива и каждого нулевого элемента (первого числа) предшествующих ему массивов.

Comment: Хорошо бы вам серьезно поработать над структурностью того, как вы излагаете свои мысли. Изложения пописать, очерки вида "как я сходил погулять" и так далее. Потому что сейчас вы пишете так, что понять вас решительно невозможно ни с первого, ни со второго, ни пятнадцатого раза.

Comment: Собственно, код у вас аналогичный - например, вы сначала выделяете память под массив, а потом запрашиваете размер. Это также комично, как сначала выпить кипяток, а потом в пустую кружку бросить чайный пакетик.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш профессиональный программистский юмор. Замечания учту, но проблему они не решили.  Дам Вам совет - задумайтесь над тем, чтобы искоренить из жизни желание "учить" других посредством пустой критики.  Я новичок и заранее извинился за глупый вопрос, так как не обладаю должными знаниями чтобы, как минимум, сформулировать его более корректно, а Вы попросту потратили своё время впустую.

Comment: Вы не находите, что теперь вы пытаетесь учить меня в ответ? (Это не ответная нападка, это очередное указание на то, что у вас трудности и последовательным мышлением). У меня критика вполне предметная, с примерами ваших ошибок в рассуждениях. Кроме того, я не единственный человек, который сетовал на то, что вас тяжело понять (@Harry). Когда критика аргументирована и содержит варианты решения предложенной проблемы, она называется *конструктивной*. Конструктивная критика, как правило, полезна.

Comment: Притча для понимания - к вам обратились на улице пешеходы и сказали - Босс, у вас шнурки распущены. А вы в ответ - Не смейте меня учить! Я хожу как хочу! На этих словах вы совершаете крутое и грузное пике прямо в лужу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не выводить пирамидальную пирамидку :), то

```
int a, b;
cout << "Введите предпоследний элемент массива:";
cin >> a;
cout << "Введите последний элемент массива:";
cin >> b;
cout << b-a;
```

Результат от всех предыдущих чисел массива не зависит.

Раз нужна именно пирамидка... Ну вот пример (только мне вводить руками не хочется, я заполняю случайными числами):

```
int main()
{
    int n = 12;
    int * v = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int d = rand()%20;
        cout << setw(6) << d;
        v[i] = d;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < n; ++j) cout << setw(6) << (v[j] -= v[i]);
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

https://ideone.com/7rRxxT

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ и участие в теме. Не совсем то что нужно. Моя ошибка, не уточнил что вопрос именно про оформление цикла, который будет выполнять n-1 итерацию. Сейчас дополню тему существующим кодом

Comment: Это вас устроит? если, конечно, я правильно понял, что вы хотите...

Comment: Знаете, последний вариант это именно тот результат который мне нужен. Буду разбираться с кодом и адаптировать под свои цели. Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Ну, если ответ вас устраивает — можете его принять (птичка слева от вопроса).

Comment: Да, безумно Вам благодарен.  Теперь разобрался с поставленным вопрос.  Вы тот самый знаток которого я искал :)